Minimum intersection of multiple sets
If we have four sets $A, B, C, D$, where, for example
$n(A) = 72$
$n(B) = 78$
$n(C) = 75$
$n(D) = 80$
and $n(A∪B∪C∪D) = 100$.
Then what is the minimum value of $n(A∩B∩C∩D)$?
In class we got the answer by minimizing $n(A∩B)$ [by maximizing $n(A∪B)$], then by minimizing $n(C∩(A∩B))$ [by maximizing $n(C∩(A∪B))$], and so on.
This method implies that all the values can be found in any two sets, or alternatively, to minimize the quadruple intersection, we must put all the values in triple intersections.
I'm able to go from the assumption that "$n(A∪B)=100$" to "all values must lie in triple intersections." However, I can't understand why we can make the first assumption? What is the intuition/proof behind it?
Alternatively, if you could provide an intuition for "all values must lie in triple intersections" alone, that would also be appreciated.

What is $n$? Is it the cardinal?

The other way to think about the problem is maximising the number of elements that get left out of at least one set. If a set has $78$ elements, it can leave out $22$. So the number that can be left out in your example will be $20 + 22 + 25 + 28 = 95$. It would be wasteful for two sets to leave out the same element.

Imagine that you have 100 balls and 72 of them have a red dot, 78 have a yellow dot, 75 have a green dot and 80 have a blue dot. And you have to arrange the dots in a way to minimise the number of balls which have all four dots. Balls which have only three dots are fine.
Now let's imagine that we have a solution which has at least one ball with all four dots. Let's prove that the mentioned statements must hold:
"all values must lie in triple intersections": In our example, it means that all balls in our solution which do not have all four dots, have three dots. Let's prove it by contradiction. If there was a ball which has less than three dots, then we can move on it one dot from a ball which has all four dots. After doing so, we would get an even better solution but we asserted that this was already the best solution.
"$n(A\cup B)=100$": In our example, it means that all balls have a red dot, a yellow dot or both. We can also prove this by contradiction. If there was a ball which didn't have neither red or a yellow dot, we could move there one dot from a ball which has all four dots. And we would again get a better solution, which is a contradiction.
